# Conditional formatting - AND ISNOTBLANK

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I would like a condition where if G2="Y" H2 to be red but then if H2 has a date/any info the cell format is back to normal

So far I have:
=AND($G$2="Y",$H$2<>"")

But this does the opposite in that H2 is unformatted whether G2 has Y or not but then when G2 has Y H2 is only formatted when it contains data.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `=AND($G$2="Y",$H$2=="")` - you want it red when `G2` is `Y` *and* `H2` is *blank*.